# Is $\csc^{-1}(u)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\right)$ a valid trigonometric identity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

I thinking about how to write inverse trig functions as each other, eg writing arccsc as some form of arctan, etc. Can anyone tell me if what I did was right? If not why? Here is what I did:

Start with

$$\csc^{-1}(u)=y$$

so

$$\csc(y)=u$$

Draw a right-angled triangle from the acute reference angle $y$, that has hypotenuse side $u$ and opposite side $1$. So it follows that the adjacent side is $\sqrt{u^2-1}$.

From this we can see that:

$$\tan(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}$$

$$y=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\right)$$

And so we have the identity:

$$\csc^{-1}(u)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\right)$$

Is this identity I derived correct?

Comment: Your formula is correct, but only for $u>1$, for $u<-1$ you need to change the sign. In general, when dealing with trigonometric identities you need to be careful with the signs. For acute angles there's usually no problems, but for other cases using a right triangle won't suffice to prove the identities. For example, the identity $\cos(x) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$ is not valid for all $x$.

Comment: Person, could you read my answer? Tell me if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

As Jjagmath pointed out, the identity you derived is correct only for $\,u>1\,,\,$ whereas you need to change the sign for $\,u<-1\,.$

The function $\,y=\csc(x)\,$ is invertible on $\,\left[-\dfrac{\pi}2,0\right)\bigcup\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}2\right]\,$ and its inverse function is

$x=\csc^{-1}(y):\!\big(\!-\!\infty,-1\big]\bigcup\big[1,+\infty\big)\!\to\!\left[-\dfrac{\pi}2,0\right)\bigcup\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}2\right].$

On the other hand, the function $\,y=\tan(x)\,$ is invertible on the interval $\,\left(-\dfrac{\pi}2,\dfrac{\pi}2\right)\,$ and its inverse function is

$x=\tan^{-1}(y):\big(\!-\infty,+\infty\big)\to\left(-\dfrac{\pi}2,\dfrac{\pi}2\right)\,.$

For any $\,y\in\big(\!-\infty,-1\big)\,,\,$ let $\,x=\csc^{-1}(y)\in\left(-\dfrac{\pi}2,0\right)\,.$
It results that $\;y=\csc(x)\,,\,$ $\sin x<0\,,\,$ $\cos x>0\,$ and

$\begin{align}\tan(x)&=\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\dfrac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}}=\dfrac{\sin x}{\left|\sin x\right|\sqrt{\dfrac1{\sin^2(x)}-1}}=\\&=-\dfrac1{\sqrt{\dfrac1{\sin^2(x)}-1}}=-\dfrac1{\sqrt{\csc^2(x)-1}}\,.\end{align}$

Since $\,y=\csc(x)\,,\,$ the function $\,\tan(x)\,$ is invertible on $\,\left(-\dfrac{\pi}2,\dfrac{\pi}2\right)\,$ and $\,x\in\left(-\dfrac{\pi}2,0\right)\,,\,$ it follows that

$x=\tan^{-1}\left(\!-\dfrac1{\sqrt{\csc^2(x)-1}}\!\right)=-\tan^{-1}\left(\!\dfrac1{\sqrt{y^2-1}}\!\right)\,.$

Consequently,

$\csc^{-1}(y)=-\tan^{-1}\left(\!\dfrac1{\sqrt{y^2-1}}\!\right)\quad$ for any $\;y\in\big(\!-\infty,-1\big)\,.$

Analogously, you can prove that

$\csc^{-1}(y)=\tan^{-1}\left(\!\dfrac1{\sqrt{y^2-1}}\!\right)\quad$ for any $\;y\in\big(1,+\infty\big)\,.$